# how to group numbers into groups on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of numbers in python for example 56,78,40,10,13,15,60,2,6 and want to group them into 
High for values 80-100
Medium for values 50-79 
low for values 0-49
How would I write the code to do this and reprint the list in those categories 
Thank you

Comment: What did you try so far Frankie Phillips?

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension :

```
L = [56,78,40,10,13,15,60,2,6]

high = [n for n in L if 80<n<100]
print(high)
# []

medium = [n for n in L if 50<n<79]
print(medium)
# [56, 78, 60]

low = [n for n in L if 0<n<49]
print(low)
# [40, 10, 13, 15, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
L = [56,78,40,10,13,15,60,2,6]
high = filter(lambda x: 80<x<100, L)
low  = filter(lambda x: 50<x<79, L)

print( "High: {}\nLow : {}".format(list(high),list(low)) )
```